# How do I markup code examples with HTML5?

Tags: html

How do I markup command line examples with HTML5?

For example:

```
cmd1
cmd2 --help
cmd3 --verbose
```

Wrapping that in a `<pre>` doesn't feel correct. Is there a better way to use HTML5 elements to express command line examples?

Comment: sounds like `<pre>` is perfect for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `<pre>` and `<code>`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-pre-element.html), one of the standard/intended uses of the `<pre>` tag is to display fragments of computer code, so your usage seems to be correct to me.